Jupyter notebook in VS Code cannot find GPU
I bought a new laptop and installed VS Code and Tensorflow on Windows. The TF Python script needs a conda virtual environment that can access Nvidia GPU card. I got the virtual environment working fine. I also got the TF Python scripts working in VS Code. However, when I use the same scripts in Jupyter notebook in VS Code, it cannot find the GPU. Both run the same virtual environment. The first screenshot shows it works in .py in VS Code:

Strangely, the same scripts in Jupyter notebook form cannot find the GPU. Please help.


One thing worth noting is that my other computers/laptops have the same setup and they don't have this problem. This laptop has the 4090 laptop GPU and somehow I can't fix the problem.

It looks like a bug in VS Code. I was about to give up running TF on Windows with VS Code, and so installed Docker desktop app. Then it started to work. In other words, after I installed Docker desktop on the Windows, the VS Code and Jupyter notebook are able to use GPU.
Thanks everyone who helped.

Could you kindly elaborate on exactly how Docker fixed the issue?

Honestly, I don't know. I was about to give up running TF natively on Windows. I also heard running TF on WSL is problematic too. So I wanted to give Docker a try. Then after installing Docker desktop, I found the original problem went away.

One of these should either fix it or send you in the right direction.

Set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
import tensorflow as tf
# More tensorflow code here


Manually set the GPU device with...
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    # Your TensorFlow code here


Make sure the Jupyter Notebook is using the same kernel as the command-line with !which python or !where python or !conda env list If it's what you said in your question, you're probably okay.

Look at which version of TensorFlow you've got installed. If it's pre-2.1, you'll need tensorflow-gpu and not tensorflow. Again, you're probably okay here, too.

Many problems are fixed by manually restarting the Jupyter kernel.



Thanks. But none of them worked. :(
I do find that Jupyter notebook works if I run VS Code from Command Prompt that has the conda environment already. In other words, I start a conda enabled Command Prompt and then activate the tensorflow conda environment. Then start VS Code. Then run the Jupyter notebook in VS Code.

I compared the settings.json for both user and workbench between this problem laptop and another similar laptop. They are identical. This is just very odd.
